# KnockOut Radio Button observableArray

Tags: html, knockout.js

I am knew to knockout.

Basically I have:

```
 self.availableNumbers = ko.observableArray(['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six'])
```

However when I try:

```
<input type="radio" data-bind="options: $root.availableNumbers(), value: number" />
```

It doesnt display a group of radio buttons with the values within the array.

Any suggestions?

jmcall10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid that Knockout won't generate a group of radio buttons like that. You would either have to manually create each radio button and give it a value yourself or you could try something like this:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: availableNumbers">
    <input type="radio" name="availableNumbersGroup" data-bind="attr: {value: $data}, checked: $root.selectedNumber" />
    <span data-bind="text:$data"></span>
    <br/>
</div>
```

This should generate a radio button for each of the available numbers in the observableArray. You'll have to create another observable to store the selected value:

```
self.selectedNumber = ko.observable("one");
```

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not wrong, the `options` binding works only with the `<select>` tag. If you want a group of radio button, the best option is to use a `foreach` binding